# Spring 3 set web application datasource based on connection string queried using another datasource

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring web application that uses 2 databases. One database has connections strings information and other has business data. So, I would like to set the second datasource based on connection string queried from first datasource. How can this be done? Any ideas please.
I have datasource definitions in the following syntax:

```
<bean id="userDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver" />
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:sybase:Tds:127.0.0.1:2999?ServiceName=db" />
   <property name="username" value="user" />
  <property name="password" value="pass" />
</bean>
```

Comment: any ideas guys or the question is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second database connection depends on the content queried from the first database, you have to first create a DAO object from the first database and then issue a query to find out the required connection information for the second database, such as url, username, passwprd. After you get all information from the first DB, you can use `getConnection` method of `DriverManager` class to get the JDBC connection:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Then you can start using the second DB from there.

Comment: Thank you tonga, I agree on the idea. I have already tried it with DriverManagerDataSource setUrl, setUsername & setPassword methods.